# how to sort A CLASS (not a struct) of objects by its different attributes?

Tags: c++

Edit here is my code:

```
class Book{
private:
int Serialnumber;
string Author; // I also have getters and setters for them
}
class Library{
vector<Book> inventory; // I added some books in the vector Inventory
}
```

I also have 2 header and 2 .cpp files for both classes. included both the headers in each .cpp files and declared both the classes in each .cpp files so I can access them.
I now need to sort my vector<> inventory.
i need 2 functions, one for sorting them by their  serial number and another to sort them by their Authors names.

Comment: `A CLASS (not a struct)` a `class` and a `struct` only differ in the default access modifier, so the method of sorting them is the same.

Comment: You could try [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) and write your own comparison function

Comment: What have you tried and what is the problem you encountered?

Comment: sorry but I specifically wrote A CLASS because of a reason. I searched the net and all the answers i could find were based on Struct which didnt help me somehome. I have used the std::sort function to sort the vector by its Serian Number (int) and it was pretty easy. I now need to write a function to sort them by Author (string) but i cant overload the std::sort funciton.

Comment: @DerChieef You need to show your code - preferably in a [mre]. What do you mean by "_cant overload the `std::sort` function_"? You are not supposed to.

Comment: I editted my code pls take a look at it. sorry im new to stackoverflow

Comment: `// I also have getters and setters for them` So show them, because it's those readers will need to use to sort, so don't make them guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in c++ there is no significant difference between class and structure. Basically, all the difference is in the perception of the programmer and the default access rights, so you can sort them simply by the function [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) and writing for it 2 different comparators

so my implementation would looks like this(NOTE: you can easely replace class with struct)

```
class book //your custom class
{
private:
    string author;
    int pages;
public: 
    book(const string &str, int num): author(str), pages(num) {} 
    friend bool pages_compare(const book& lhs, const book& rhs); //friend comparator. If your fields are public, you may remove "friendship"
    friend bool author_compare(const book& lhs, const book& rhs);//friend comparator. If your fields are public, you may remove "friendship"
    friend void print(const book& arg);
};

bool pages_compare(const book& lhs, const book& rhs) // func for sorting by pages count
{
    return lhs.pages < rhs.pages;
}

bool author_compare(const book& lhs, const book& rhs) // func for sorting by author name
{
    return lhs.author < rhs.author;
}

void print(const book& arg) // custom printing
{
    cout << '{' << arg.author << ", " << arg.pages << "} ";
}

int main()
{
    book book0{"aurelius", 10};
    book book1{"bbbbbb", 5};
    book book2{"ccccc", 15};
    book book3{"au", 100};
    vector<book> arr = {book0, book1, book2, book3};
    sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), pages_compare); // sort by page count
    for(auto &i: arr) // print
        print(i); // {bbbbbb, 5} {aurelius, 10} {ccccc, 15} {au, 100} 
    cout << '\n';
    sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), author_compare); // sort by author name
    for(auto &i: arr) // print
        print(i); // {au, 100} {aurelius, 10} {bbbbbb, 5} {ccccc, 15} 
}
```

Comment: I have used the std::sort function to sort the vector by its Serian Number (int) and it was pretty easy. I now need to write a function to sort them by Author (string) but i cant overload the std::sort funciton. 
and unfortunately i couldnt initialize the friend function in my .cpp file

Comment: @DerChieef as I showed in my code, pass third parameter to the sort function. Third parameter is used as comparator(so sorting rule) for your array. 
And you need friend function only if you want to compare your class by private member

Comment: so everything will be the same, but remove friend function declaration from the class, and inside comparing function call getters instead of members itself